# Ajax php contact form no email

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, formmail

Cannot seem to get this code to work it's says it sending the email but somewhere on the line it's get stuck. have not access to the logs at this moment from the host, so can't check and this should send the emails from my point of view atht this moment

```
//check if its an ajax request, exit if not
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

    //exit script outputting json data
    $output = json_encode(
    array(
        'type'=>'error',
        'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
    ));

    die($output);
}

//check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userMessage"]))
{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'The input fields are empty!'));
    die($output);
}

//Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
$user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$user_Phone             = $_POST["userTelephone"];
$user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//additional php validation
if(strlen($user_Name)<3) // If length is less than 3 it will throw an HTTP error.
{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name field can not be empty'));
    die($output);
}
if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please use a valid email address'));
    die($output);
}

if(strlen($user_Message)<5) //check emtpy message
{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a message'));
    die($output);
}


$message_Body = "<strong>Name: </strong>". $user_Name ."<br>";
$message_Body .= "<strong>Email: </strong>". $user_Email ."<br>";
$message_Body .= "<strong>Phone: </strong>". $user_Phone ."<br>";
$message_Body .= "<strong>Message: </strong>". $user_Message ."<br>";



$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($user_Email) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($user_Email) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";



//proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
'Content-type: text/html';



$sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $message_Body, $headers);

if(!$sentMail)
{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'An error has occurred, please try again'));
    die($output);
}else{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hello '.$user_Name .'Thanks for your contact we will return soon.'));
    die($output);
}
}
```

here is the JS

```
  $("#submit_btn").click(function() {
            //get input field values
            var user_name       = $('input[name=name]').val();
            var user_email      = $('input[name=email]').val();
            var user_telephone      = $('input[name=phone]').val();
            var user_message    = $('textarea[name=message]').val();

            //simple validation at client's end
            var post_data, output;
            var proceed = true;
            if(user_name==""){
                    proceed = false;
            }
            if(user_email==""){
                    proceed = false;
            }
            if(user_message=="") {
                    proceed = false;
            }

            //everything looks good! proceed...
            if(proceed)
            {
                    //data to be sent to server
                    post_data = {'userName':user_name, 'userEmail':user_email, 'userTelephone':user_telephone, 'userMessage':user_message};

                    //Ajax post data to server
                    $.post('contact.php', post_data, function(response){

                            //load json data from server and output message
            if(response.type == 'error')
            {
                output = '<div class="alert-danger" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:25px;">'+response.text+'</div>';
            }else{
                output = '<div class="alert-success" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:25px;">'+response.text+'</div>';

                //reset values in all input fields
                $('#form-elements input').val('');
                $('#form-elements textarea').val('');
            }

            $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
                    }, 'json');

            }
    });

    //reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
    $("#form-elements input, #form-elements textarea").keyup(function() {
            $("#result").slideUp();
    });
```

html

```
  <form id="form-elements" onSubmit="return false">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 center"><div id="result"> </div> </div>
                     </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Namn" name="name" id="name" required></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Adress" name="email" id="email" required></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefon nummer" name="phone" id="phone" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <textarea id="input" class="form-control" rows="7" required="required" placeholder="Meddelande" name="message" id="message" ></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default buttons" id="submit_btn">Skicka</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dunno but some othere said i should insert

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function() {
 e.preventDefault();
```

is the problem that I using ?

```
onSubmit="return false"
```